# Dynamically adding values from radio buttons into an array and then adding those values together for result with jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, dynamic

I'm basically working on a quiz and all I want to do is get the values from the selected radio buttons, add them together and return the result. There 8 questions total. But the way this quiz functions is that there are previous and next buttons which allows the user to go back and change their answer(s). So I would then need to get the value for that specific question and replace it with the new value, if the user chooses to change their answer. All the questions are on the page statically and are just shown and hidden via jquery. Just need some help. Doesn't need to post to a server. Just need to retain the results and return the total after the user is completed. I don't have any code to post for starting this process. Thanks. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Why don't you just get the values at the time your submit the quiz? Or how should it work? What does *return the result* mean? Do you POST it to a server?

Comment: there's no posting to a server. there needs to be variables set up to retain the value(s) and then i can just return the variable that contains the total, if that makes sense. there is no actual form submission.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** to answer the additional questions in the comments

Hi Brian,

It's probably best to create an onChange handler and store the answers in an object, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    answers = new Object()
    $('.option').change(function(){
        var answer = ( $(this).attr('value') )
        var question = ( $(this).attr('name') )
        answers[question] = answer
    })
    $('#done').click(function(){
        var result = sum_values()
        // do stuff with the result
        alert('the sum of the recorded values is: ' + result)
    })
})

function sum_values(){
    var the_sum = 0
    for (question in answers){
        the_sum = the_sum + parseInt(answers[question])
    }
    return the_sum
}


<input class='option' type="radio" name="question1" value="1">answer 1 to Q1<br>
<input class='option' type="radio" name="question1" value="2">answer 2 to Q1<br>
<hr>
<input class='option' type="radio" name="question2" value="1">answer 1 to Q2<br>
<input class='option' type="radio" name="question2" value="2">answer 2 to Q2<br>
<span id='done' style='cursor:pointer;'>done</div>
```

this will leave you with an answers object that is updated whenever a radio box is selected or changed. You can sum up the values by calling sum_values(), in this example when the user clicks 'done'.

Hope this helps,

Hoff

Comment: this sort of works. i need to be able to add all the values at the end of the quiz when the user clicks on the submit button. what's the best way of doing that?

Comment: going back to my previous comment, so if the user chooses to go back and change an answer, that value needs to replace what was there originally, then i need to be able to add all the values within the array to get my result. if this doesn't make sense, please let me know.

Comment: hi brian, when the a radio button for a given question is first selected, the key/value pair will be added in the object (e.g. answers['question1'] is say '2' and answers['question2'] is '2'. then if the user goes back to question 1 and changes it, this will update the value of answers['question1'] to '1'. I don't understand what you mean by ", then i need to be able to add all the values within the array" - add all the values to what?

Comment: basically i need to take the values that are in the array, out of the 8 questions, and add them to get a score. Then from there i can show a particular screen depending on what the user's score is. does that help any?